# pascal triangle gives overflow for 13

Tags: vb.net, biginteger, pascals-triangle

I wrote a code to output Pascal triangle in a multi-line textbook. The program works fine for inputs between 1 to 12 but gives an overflow error once a value of 13 is inputed.

Is there any modifications I can make to enable the program to accurately give outputs for 13 and higher?

Here is the code I used:

```
Public Class pascal_triangle

    Private Function factorial(ByVal k As Integer) As Integer
        If k = 0 Or k = 1 Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return k * factorial(k - 1)
        End If
    End Function


    Private Sub BtnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGen.Click
        Dim nCr As Integer
        Dim i, j, k As Integer
        Dim output As String

        output = ""

        j = Val(TxtColumn.Text)

        For k = 0 To j
            For i = 0 To k
                Dim fact, fact1, fact2 As Integer

                fact = factorial(k)
                fact1 = factorial(k - i)
                fact2 = factorial(i)
                nCr = fact / (fact1 * fact2)
                TxtOutput.Text += Str(nCr) & output
            Next
            TxtOutput.Text += vbCrLf
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow is because `13!` is too big to fit in an integer.

The largest representable `integer` (32-bit signed)  is

- 2147483647  (0x7FFFFFFF ==  01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111b)

so :

```
 12!    =  479001600  
 MaxInt = 2147483647
 13!    = 6227020800
```

If you want to use larger numbers than this you need to use a larger number type.  The next larger types are `Long` (64-bit signed, max `9223372036854775807`) or, for your purposes, `ULong` (unsigned 64-bit, since you don't need negative numbers, which is twice that at `18446744073709551615`).

This will let you calculate up to`20!`, which is `2432902008176640000`.  For numbers larger than this you will need to look into using either [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or other dedicated libraries that allow for holding and calculating arbitrarily large numbers.

Alternatively, you can look into other methods of computing an arbitrary row [without using factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself).

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are using `Integer` which is too small to hold the factorial of 13. Change your Factorial function to return `Long`. It would also be a good idea to turn `Option Strict On` and make `nCr` a `Double`.

```
Private Function factorial(ByVal k As Integer) As Long
    If k = 0 Or k = 1 Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return k * factorial(k - 1)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub BtnGen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGen.Click
    Dim nCr As Double
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(TxtColumn.Text, j)
    For k = 0 To j
        For i = 0 To k
            Dim fact, fact1, fact2 As Long
            fact = factorial(k)
            fact1 = factorial(k - i)
            fact2 = factorial(i)
            nCr = fact / (fact1 * fact2)
            TxtOutput.Text += nCr.ToString & " "
        Next
        TxtOutput.Text += vbCrLf
    Next
End Sub
```